# Kivy: show action bar on all screens

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to show an 'action bar' on all screens, without copying and pasting the code to all the screens.

My question is  if it possible or not?

here is the kv file:

```
Manager:
    Screen_one:
    Screen_two:
    Screen_three:

<Screen_one>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        size: root.size

        ActionBar:
            background_color: 0, .4, .7, 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '35dp'
            ActionView:
                use_separator: True
                ActionPrevious:
                    title: 'Menu:'
                    with_previous: False
                ActionOverflow:
                ActionButton:
                    important: True
                    text: 'Print'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Declare a root with inheritance of a `BoxLayout` widget
2. Instantiate `ActionBar` and `ScreenManager` widgets as children of root

## Snippets

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ActionBar:
        ...
    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        Screen_one:
        Screen_two:
        Screen_three:

<Screen_one>:
    ...
```